# What are the requirements to set up a Deutsche Bank account?

Tags: banking, bank-account, non-resident, germany

I'm 17 and would like to move to Germany when I graduate high school in the US to study there. I will be visiting friends in Berlin this Christmas to scout out universities and possible living situations.

At this time I would like to start to transfer my funds to a DB account. I've looked online and I like the accounts and their online banking solutions the best.

What do I need to bring as far as documentation goes?
Is it even wise to set up those accounts in December or should I wait until June 2018, when I move?

Comment: You could call the US branch of DB and ask them if they can assist you: https://www.db.com/usa/content/en/Contact.html You also may need a special account to even get a student visa. See https://www.deutsche-bank.de/pk/konto-und-karte/konten-im-ueberblick/internationale-studenten1.html (in english)